# How to recover x name product and x price product in js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several (1 - 30) products which I display, but I don't know how to get all product information (name, price and quantity) in a JS table when I click on a button.

Here is my code:

```
    $.each(details, function(i, obj) {

    $("#ProduitLie").append('<div id="EachProduitlie" class="EachProduitlie">
    <div id="dimImg" class="dimImg" ">'+obj.imgproduit+'</div>
    <div id="eachnom"  ">'+obj.nomproduit+'</div>
    <div id="eachprix" ">prix :'+obj.prixproduit+' €</div>
    <input class="eachboxnumber" type="number" step="1" value="1" min="1" max="10"></div>');

    });
```

and this is a picture of my each()

[image: example]

Comment: typo `...class="dimImg" "...` and 2 more times fix those first

Comment: __Identifiers in HTML must be unique.__

Comment: you cannot have same identifiers (IDs) for multiple elements in HTML!

Comment: ok i did like this with a cpt like this in each div 

<div id="dimImg'+cpt+'" class="dimImg" ">'+obj.imgproduit+'</div> cpt++;

but the problems is always there lol